# Getting the sum of several columns from two tables result is not correct

Tags: mysql, join

I'am trying to get the sum of the two columns from different tables, however i have found great posts on stack. some of them helped me out. but i still can't solve this problem out..

This query somehow down below returns incorrect total of the sum of the coulmns, ( rate Coulmn - materialprice Column )

```
mysql> Tbl  as_servicetickets;
+----------+----------+
|ticket_id |  rate    |
+----------+----------+
|       11 |   250.00 |
|       11 |   300.00 |
|       11 |   400.00 |
|        9 |   300.00 |
|        9 |   300.00 |
|        9 |  1500.00 |
|        9 |   250.00 |
+----------+----------+
total is 2 350.00

mysql> Tbl as_ticketmaterials;
+----------+---------------+
|ticket_id | materialprice |
+----------+---------------+
|       11 |           100 |
|        9 |            20 |
|        9 |            50 |
+----------+---------------+
total is 70.00
```

query---------------------////

```
SELECT SUM(`as_servicetickets`.`rate`) AS `sercnt`,  SUM(`as_ticketmaterials`.`materialprice`) AS `sercnt`
FROM  `as_servicetickets`, `as_ticketmaterials`
WHERE `as_servicetickets`.`ticket_id` = 9
AND   `as_ticketmaterials`.`ticket_id` = 9
GROUP BY `as_servicetickets`.`ticket_id`, `as_ticketmaterials`.`ticket_id

result ------------------///// this is not correct
+---------+--------+
| sercnt  | sercnt |
+---------+--------+
| 4700.00 |    280 |
+---------+--------+
```

Comment: The totals are correct, the query is not. Explain what do you want to accomplish and what is the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to achieve the desired result. Try this rather:-

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(`as_servicetickets`.`rate`) AS `sercnt`
        FROM `as_servicetickets`
        WHERE `as_servicetickets`.`ticket_id` = 9),
       (SELECT  SUM(`as_ticketmaterials`.`materialprice`) AS `sercnt`
        FROM  `as_ticketmaterials`
        WHERE `as_ticketmaterials`.`ticket_id` = 9);
```

Comment: does this query will affect the performance badly. i know i have got to avoid sub queries, but sometimes you don't have other ways to solve out this tricks.

Comment: Yes it will affect some performance but i think there is no other way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: yes, you are right..i have checked out tons of posts on stack. most of posts are encouraging developers to avoid sub query..instead joins are greet when dealing table joins. but most of them uses sub queries. anyway...Once more Thanks Ankit Bajpai...

Answer (score 1):

Try using explicit join as implicit joins are discouraged (You where condition has issue)

```
SELECT `as_servicetickets`.`ticket_id`, SUM(`as_servicetickets`.`rate`) AS `sercnt`,  SUM(`as_ticketmaterials`.`materialprice`) AS `sercnt`
FROM  `as_servicetickets` INNER JOIN `as_ticketmaterials`
ON `as_servicetickets`.`ticket_id` = `as_ticketmaterials`.`ticket_id` 
WHERE `as_servicetickets`.`ticket_id` = 9
GROUP BY `as_servicetickets`.`ticket_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(a.rate) as sercnt, sum(b.materialprice) as sercnt from
as_servicetickets a inner join as_ticketmaterials b on 
a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id  where a.ticket_id = 9
```

Comment: Hey there Shailesh. It's better to explain your answer with words too: explain why this should work.